# Set in the BundleConfig but load script fail - MVC4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have set the bundleConfig file like this :

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MyTest").Include("~/Scripts/test.js").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/test.init.js")); 
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Angular").Include("~/Scripts/angular.min.js"));
```

I call them is my Layout like this :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Angular") <!-- ERROR -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MyTest") <!-- SUCCESS -->
```

Where's my error, please ?

http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/noel-rice/2012/09/19/adding-your-own-scripts-and-style-sheets-to-mvc-4-bundles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bundling in ASP.NET MVC will ignore files ending with .min.js. You will have to add the development version of the file.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Angular").Include("~/Scripts/angular.js"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Angular").Include("~/Scripts/angular.js"));
```

.NET will add .min for you if you are not in debug